# Rolling Quine Dice

Tags: code-golf, random, quine

Create a program that outputs itself.

However, if the source code is repeated n times *(meaning to concatenate a copy of the source code to the end n-1 times)*, then there should be 1/n probability outputting the original source code, a 1/n probability of outputting the source code repeated twice, a 1/n probability of outputting the source code repeated three times, ..., and a 1/n probability of outputting the source code n times.

For example, if your program is `foobar`, then it should always output exactly `foobar`.
However, if you run `foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar`, then there should be a ¼ chance each of outputting `foobar`, `foobarfoobar`, `foobarfoobarfoobar` and `foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar`.

- The distribution of each possible output should be equal
- In addition to standard I/O methods applying and standard loopholes forbidden, standard quine rules apply (can't access its own source, etc.)
- This is code golf so shortest answer in bytes wins

Comment: Is pseudorandom good enough?

Comment: @wastl Yep, that's alright

Comment: Your definition is slightly off. If you repeat it 1 time (i.e. `foobarfoobar`) then it'd only print `foobar`

Comment: @Veskah `foobarfoobar` is `foobar` repeated two times, not once.

Comment: @Nit You start with the source. If you use it again, you have only repeated it once but have two instances.

Comment: @Veskah I'd say this is just not how the phrase works, but "by concatenating a copy of the source code to the end n times" seems to imply what you say. However, then the probabilities don't add up to 1.

Comment: Yeah, I'll clear up the ambiguity. I would agree for repeating 3 times would be `foobarfoobarfoobar` but that would be inconsistent

Answer (score 13):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>82</s> 80 bytes

```perl
$s=q($s=q(%s);printf"$s\n+1#",$s for 0..rand);printf"$s\n+1#",$s for 0..rand
+1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@l2LZQA0yoFmtaFxRl5pWkKakUx@RpGyor6agUK6TlFykY6OkVJealEJLnAor9/w8A) or [Test suite](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lOT8lVcFWQcUxyD0s2iC2AsIwjLXmKijKzCtRUFIAAteK1OTSksy8dKuYPLCOmDyQcFBqcWlOCVBMyZortSwxRwEsZ/0faGyxbaEGmFAt1rQGm5SmpFIck6dtqKyko1KskJZfpGCgp1eUmJdCSJ4LKPbfCAA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
“Ṿ;ẋŻɼLX¤¤µ”Ṿ;ẋŻɼLX¤¤µ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZP9zVfXT3yT0@EYeWAOHWRw1zsYj@/w8A)

[Try it x4!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZP9zVfXT3yT0@EYeWAOHWRw1zsYoOvNr//wE)

```
“Ṿ;ẋŻɼLX¤¤µ”Ṿ;ẋŻɼLX¤¤µ
“Ṿ;ẋŻɼLX¤¤µ”              String literal: Ṿ;ẋŻɼLX¤¤µ
            Ṿ             Uneval. Return “Ṿ;ẋŻɼLX¤¤µ” (with quotes)
             ;            Append the initial string. Yields the source code. 
                ɼ         Apply the preceding link to the register and store the 
                          result in the register.
               Ż          Prepend 0. 
                          Each time Żɼ is used when the source code is repeated
                          the register's length increases by one. 
                          We can't use ‘ because it closes string literals.
                 L        Length. Returns the number of times the source code has
                          been repeated up till now.
                  X       Random element. If ɼ results in n, X returns a random 
                          integer between 1 and n.
                   ¤      Combines ŻɼLX as a nilad. 
              ẋ           Repeat the source code a random number of times between
                          1 and n.
                    ¤     Close everything from the initial string literal as a
                          nilad. 
                     µ    Start a new monadic chain. The register gets updated
                          once for time the code is repeated but only the final
                          repetition will result in output.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 32 bytes

```
"34çìDJ¼32ôн¾L×Ω"34çìDJ¼32ôн¾L×Ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fydjk8PLDa1y8Du0xNjq85cLeQ/t8Dk8/txKX@P//AA)

**Explanation**

```
"34çìDJ¼32ôн¾L×Ω"                   # push this string
                 34ç                # push a "-character
                    ì               # prepend it to the string
                     DJ             # duplicate and join the copy to the string
                       ¼            # increment the counter
                        32ô         # split the string into pieces of size 32
                           н        # take the first one
                            ¾L×     # repeat it for each in [1 ... counter]
                               Ω    # pick one at random
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation when you have a chance?

Comment: @Shaggy: Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 21 bytes

```
:QoaonC|P\Sx*F2ssS"
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3yowPzE/z7kmICa4QsvNqLg4WInL4P9/AA)

#### Explanation:

```
:Q     |     If the top of stack is 0, skip to next |
             Top of stack is implicitly 0
        P    Increment top of stack
         \   Redirect pointer down]
0:QoaonC|P\Sx*F2ssS"  Increment for each copy of the source code
0:QoaonC|P\Sx*F2ssS"


         \   Redirect back to the right
          Sx*  Multiply the number of copies of the source code by a random number between 0 and 1
             F      Repeat that many times
              2ss   Push a double quote
                 S" Print the source code minus the quote, newline and 0
 :Q       If top of stack is not 0
   oaonC  Print the quote, a newline and a 0 to complete the source code and continue the loop
        \Sx*   Error on the * for some reason
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 35 bytes

```
"d3a*h-&;adddd12h&}Uh*t&w.odt,k@
 !
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18pxThRK0NXzToxBQgMjTLUakMztErUyvXyU0p0sh24FBT//wcA)

#### Explanation

```
"
```

Like in many quines in 2D languages, this starts with a `"` that wraps around to itself and pushes the entire first line except the `"` itself.

```
d3a*h-&;
```

Adding one or more additional copies of the source code will place some implicit spaces at the end of the string literal.  To make this actually a quine, we truncate the stack at 31 characters.

```
addd
```

Push a newline, then the stack height three times.  The values pushed as the stack height are 32 (the space in the second line), 33 (the `!` in the second line), and 34 (the initial `"`).

```
d
```

Push the stack height again, this time as the length of the original source code (35).

```
1
```

Initialize a counter at 1.  This will count the number of times the source code is repeated.

```
2h&}
```

Turn right three times in place (i.e., turn left).  Each additional repetition of the source code will contribute an `h` in the same column as this `}`, thus incrementing the counter.  When the IP returns to the `}`, turn right again to continue in the same direction.

```
Uh
```

Take a uniform random number from 0 to n-1, then add 1 to get the number of times to output the original source.

```
*t&w
```

Multiply by the previously pushed stack height (code length), then repeat the following that many times by pushing a return address that many times minus one.

```
.o
```

Output the top of the stack without destroying it.

```
dt,
```

Move the bottom stack entry to the top.

```
k@
```

Repeat, then terminate after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

```javascript
(f=a=>b=>b?f(a+.5):`(f=${f})(1)`.repeat(1+Math.random()*a))(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvFfI8020dYuCYjs0zQStfVMNa0SgGIq1Wm1mhqGmgl6RakFqYklGobavoklGXpFiXkp@bkamlqJmiDp/xqamv8B)

Comment: Either I'm very unlucky, or this can't print more than two copies of the original source code.

Comment: @Nitrodon Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 58 bytes

```
≔´θ´⎚´×´⊕´‽´Ｌ´⊞´Ｏ´υ´ω´⁺´⪫´⁺´´´≔´θ´´´´´θθ⎚×⊕‽Ｌ⊞Ｏυω⁺⪫⁺´≔θ´´θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RDW87tOLTlUd@sQ1sOTwcyuqYCiYa9h7a837MGxJ0HYq0/tOV8KxB3AkUadwGJVauhLBCEmwKD53ac2wE08fB0oGlAs4AmAc0BmnK@9XwnUBdQN8SUzikQXed2/P8PAA) No verbose version because the deverbosifier currently chokes on `"´"`. Mostly based on the Charcoal quine from [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69). Explanation:

```
≔´θ´⎚´×´⊕´‽´Ｌ´⊞´Ｏ´υ´ω´⁺´⪫´⁺´´´≔´θ´´´´´θθ
```

Assign the literal string `θ⎚×⊕‽Ｌ⊞Ｏυω⁺⪫⁺´≔θ´´θ` to `θ`.

```
⎚
```

Clear any previous output, so that only the last output takes effect.

```
×⊕‽Ｌ⊞Ｏυω
```

Push the empty string to the predefined array. This makes the array length equal to the number of repetitions processed so far, so take its length, take a random number the implicit exclusive range, add 1, and repeat the following string that many times.

```
⁺⪫⁺´≔θ´´θ
```

Prepend the literal string `≔` to `θ`, then insert literal `´`s between each character, then suffix another copy of `θ`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>118</s> 116 bytes

```python
for i in(1,c:=0):
 exec(s:="from random import*;c+=i or print('for i in(1,c:=0):\\n exec(s:=%r)#'%s*randint(1,c))")#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFTITNPw1An2crWQNOKSyG1IjVZo9jKVimtKD9XoSgxLwVIZeYW5BeVaFkna9tmKgD1FBRl5pVoqGNoj4nJgxugWqSprK5arAUyAqQaqEZTU0lT@f9/AA)